# How to combine splitn and split_whitespace in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to split crontab entries, and one of the requirements is that the last field, the command, should retain the original whitespace. In other words, given the line

```
1 2 3 4 5 command "much   whitespace"
```

the resulting structure should contain six elements, the last of which is exactly the string `command "much   whitespace"`.

So I need to do `entry.splitn(6, [something involving whitespace])` or `entry.split_whitespace([something involving 6])`. The former seems cleaner, but I can't seem to reuse any of the implementation:

- `entry.splitn(6, str::split_whitespace)` is a type mismatch
- `entry.splitn(6, entry.split_whitespace())` results in "the trait `std::ops::FnMut<(char,)>` is not implemented for `std::str::SplitWhitespace<'_>`"
- I can't simply copy the implementation of `split_whitespace` in str.rs, because `std::std_unicode::str::UnicodeStr` is private.

Is there a succinct way of combining these?

Comment: Maybe using a regex for this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
entry.splitn(6, char::is_whitespace)
```

Should work correctly for the example string. That is, if the fields are separated by exactly one whitespace character. If you are certain this is the case for crontab entries this approach is sufficient. However, as pointed out in @DK.'s answer, if there happen to be extra whitespaces between fields each of them will lead to a split.

For example, `"1 2   3 4 5 command \"much   whitespace\""` results in `"1", "2", "", "", "3", "4 5 command \"much   whitespace\""`.

The cleanest solution would probably be to manually parse the string. But as a quick and dirty solution it is possible to use `splitn` with a stateful closure:

```
fn main() {
    let entry = "1 2 3     4 5 command \"much   whitespace\"";

    let mut last_whitespace = false;

    let parts = entry.splitn(6, |c: char| {
        if c.is_whitespace() {
            if last_whitespace {
                return false
            }
            last_whitespace = true;
            true
        } else {
            last_whitespace = false;
            false
        }
    }).map(str::trim);

    let x: Vec<_> = parts.collect();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

The extra whitespaces are treated as part of the following substring, so we need to additionally trim each substring.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a succinct way of combining these?

No.  You can't use an iterator as a predicate; they're not even remotely the same thing.

You don't need access to the internal Unicode modules to test if something is whitespace: `char::is_whitespace` does that.  The *problem* is that `split_whitespace` is not just `s.split(char::is_whitespace)`.  `split` includes empty substrings between splits, `split_whitespace` does not.  As a result, if you have extra spaces in the input, these will "eat" one of the limited number of splits you want to do.

The correct solution would be to implement a custom [`Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html) that matches continuous runs of whitespace characters.  *Would* be, but isn't, because `Pattern` has been unstable since August 2015, and shows no sign of being stabilised any time soon.

Were I in your position, I would just parse the string by hand.